# Should we go for AFCI when we have Circuit breaker

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, afci, electric-heat

I know circuit breaker trips the electric supply when there's overcurrent such as short circuit.

ARC Fault leads to overcurrent so IMO circuit breakers are enough and AFCI(Arc Fault Circuit interrupter) is not needed.

Can someone clarify if this is right ?

Comment: AFC will detect and shut down you circuit before the big one

Comment: But why , Circuit breaker does the same job right ?

Comment: CB only reacts when you have full current flow, 20 Amp or 30 or 50 and so on. AFC reacts to any small arching. Full current can be damaging.

Comment: So when there's ARC wouldn't it draw higher current like 20 Amp or more ? and also can you explain me how full current can be damaging .. I mean would it damage the wire ? or other connected appliance at home ?

Comment: you are confusing a short circuit with arc. it draws way more current until the cb reacts. arching is the beginning of the short circuit. Regular cb is a mechanical device (with resistance heat element. afc is a electronic curcuit that prevents short circuit

Comment: I get it now , thanks

Comment: If you have seen seen/used welders, that is an arc.  Those welders are on a circuit breaker, some as small as 20 amps, same size as a house circuit.  An AFCI prevents that arc.

Comment: Oh is it ? Good to know thanks

Comment: Actually you should go ahead and have CAFCI ( Combined Arc Fault Circuit Interrupt ) rather than AFCI because AFCI can stop only parallel arcs but CAFCI can stop Parrallel and Serial ARCs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arc faults can be just from a loose connection.

A plain breaker will happy supply power to a loose connection, even as it is heating and burning.  The breaker will only trip if a hot wire touches ground or neutral wire.

AFCI breakers sense small arcs and will trip fast.

Comment: Won't the breaker trip when there is over current ?  I mean ARC fault should cause over current right ?

Comment: I think you are thinking of ground faults.  An AFCI senses arcs or what you would call sparks.  Sparks between a hot wire and a hot/live screw will not be an over current, but can cause a build up of heat.  When the outlet burns up and the hot comes in contact with ground/neutral the plain breaker might trip, but you will not care since you are busy trying to put out the fire.

Comment: This makes sense

Comment: AFCI, GFCI, and standard over-current breaker. All these are different things.

Answer (score 4):

> ARC Fault leads to overcurrent

That opinion is incorrect.

Two of the types of arc fault are series arcing.  In this case the arcing is in series with the load, add resistance, and thus current is less than normal.

And in certain cases, a parallel arc can have current less than the rating of the breaker - the heat damage is considerable but they are not drawing enough current to trip hte breaker.

> so IMO circuit breakers are enough and AFCI(Arc Fault Circuit interrupter) is not needed.

The NFPA certainly understands the topic better than you do.  If they were not needed, they would not be specified.  A lot of people think NEC is written by dumb New York lawyers. Not at all: it's a consensus process among design engineers and the industry.